# How to get img/src or a/hrefs using Html Agility Pack?

Tags: c#, .net, html, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I want to use the HTML agility pack to parse image and href links from a HTML page,but I just don't know much about XML or XPath.Though having looking up help documents in many web sites,I just can't solve the problem.In addition,I use C# in VisualStudio 2005.And I just can't speak English fluently,so,I will give my sincere thanks to the one can write some helpful codes.

Comment: And,can Html Agility Pack solve Relative Paths?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The [first example](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples) on the home page does something very similar, but consider:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("file.htm"); // would need doc.LoadHtml(htmlSource) if it is not a file
doc.OptionEmptyCollection = true; // avoid null reference exception
foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
{
   string href = link.Attributes["href"].Value;
   // store href somewhere
}
```

So you can imagine that for img@src, just replace each `a` with `img`, and `href` with `src`.
You might even be able to simplify to:

```
foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a/@href | //img/@src"))
{
    HtmlAttribute href = node.Attributes["href"];
    HtmlAttribute src = node.Attributes["src"];
    list.Add((href ?? src).Value);
}
```

For relative url handling, look at the `Uri` class.

Comment: I get error: DocumentElement not exists in HtmlDocument object for 1.4.0.0 version HtmlAgilitypack foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
{
HtmlAttribute att = link.Attributes["href"];

Comment: Not positive but I believe DocumentElement is now DocumentNode

Answer (score 7):

The example and the accepted answer is wrong. It doesn't compile with the latest version. I try something else:

```
    private List<string> ParseLinks(string html)
    {
        var doc = new HtmlDocument(); 
        doc.LoadHtml(html);
        var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]");
        return nodes == null ? new List<string>() : nodes.ToList().ConvertAll(
               r => r.Attributes.ToList().ConvertAll(
               i => i.Value)).SelectMany(j => j).ToList();
    }
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I am too late here to post an answer. The following worked for me:

```
var MainImageString  = MainImageNode.Attributes.Where(i=> i.Name=="src").FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);

string name = htmlDoc.DocumentNode
    .SelectNodes("//td/input")
    .First()
    .Attributes["value"].Value;
```

Source:
https://html-agility-pack.net/select-nodes

Answer (score 0):

You also need to take into account the document base URL element (`<base>`) and protocol relative URLs (for example `//www.foo.com/bar/`).

For more information check:

- [<base>: The Document Base URL element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) page on MDN
- [The Protocol-relative URL](https://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/) article by Paul Irish
- [What are the recommendations for html  tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889076/what-are-the-recommendations-for-html-base-tag) discussion on StackOverflow
- [Uri Constructor (Uri, Uri)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ceyeze4f(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN
- [Uri class doesn't handle the protocol-relative URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38135386/uri-class-doesnt-handle-the-protocol-relative-url) discussion no StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

Late post, but here's a 2021 update to the accepted answer (fixes the refactoring that HtmlAgilityPack made.

```
    var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
    htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);
    string command = "";

    // The Xpath below gets images.  
    // It is specific to a site.  Yours will vary ...
    command = "//a[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), 'product-card')]//img";  
    List<string> listImages=new();
    foreach(HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(command))
    {
        //  Using "data-src" below, but it may be "src" for you
        listImages.Add(node.Attributes["data-src"].Value);
    }
```