# Find string in string inside HTML img element

Tags: c#, substring

How can I get string that is between " and " and also is in `<IMG ... >`

So simply, how to get this:

```
file:///C:/abc.png
file:///C:/cba.png
```

from this:

```
<BODY>
    <IMG alt="" src="file:///C:/abc.png"><br>
    <IMG alt="" src="file:///C:/cba.png">
</BODY>
```

The information is received dynamically

Comment: why in csharp? I mean.. how in csharp are you reading an html page?

Comment: [Html Agility Pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) is going to make your life so much easier.

Comment: WYSIWYG, user create a note then I sending this to database and after it display on page.

Comment: @Banana How it can help me when I need to take a path of images from string with HTML code?

Comment: If you actually search on what you want to do (so: "C# find img src in html" instead of "many substring what contain another substring"), you'll find two approaches: using a RegEx and using HtmlAgilityPack. See [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835868/how-to-get-img-src-or-a-hrefs-using-html-agility-pack) for the proper approach, which is the latter.

Comment: @KariiO html agility pack presents you with a document object from which you can manipulate the html simply as html instead of a long string. see CodeCasters link or [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113924/how-can-i-use-html-agility-pack-to-retrieve-all-the-images-from-a-website) link for reference.