# Uri class doesn't handle the protocol-relative URL

Tags: c#, .net, url

*EDIT: This doesn't happen on Windows but on Mono 4.2.2 Linux ([C# Online Compiler](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_csharp_online.php)).

I want to parse the protocol-relative URL and get the host name etc. For now I insert "http:" to the head before processing it since C# Uri class couldn't handle a protocol-relative URL. Could you tell me if there's any better way or any good library?

```
    // Protocol-relative URL
    var uriString = "//www.example.com/bluh/bluh.css";
    var uri = new Uri(uriString);
    Console.WriteLine(uriString); // "//www.example.com/bluh/bluh.css"
    Console.WriteLine(uri.Host); // "Empty" string

    // Absolute URL
    var fixUriString = uriString.StartsWith("//") ? "http:" + uriString : uriString;
    var fixUri = new Uri(fixUriString);
    Console.WriteLine(fixUriString); // "http://www.example.com/bluh/bluh.css"
    Console.WriteLine(fixUri.Host); // "www.example.com"
```

Comment: Possibly you could write your own `UriParser` - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uriparser.aspx

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
    Uri uri = null;
    if(Uri.TryCreate("//forum.xda-developers.com/pixel-c", UriKind.Absolute, out uri))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(uri.Authority);
        Console.WriteLine(uri.Host);
    }
```

returns

```
forum.xda-developers.com
forum.xda-developers.com
```

It also worked for me using the `Uri(string)` constructor.

Comment: Thank you! You made me realized mono on Linux works differently. I switched to Windows then Uri(string) works perfectly.